# matrix sinônimo de matriz?

Tags: debate

Será que a tag matrix é sinônimo da tag matriz? Das 6 perguntas com essa tag 2 usam as duas tags, 3 outras são de R (onde matrix é apenas o tipo do objeto que representa uma matriz) e uma outra está falando sobre um objeto `DataMatrix` em Delphi...

Sugeri como sinônimo aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/matriz/synonyms

Comment: Talvez seja o caso de você ter escolhido a pilula vermelha ao invés da azul.

Comment: Não entendi o comentário

Comment: [Matrix](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix)

Comment: Ri alto do seu comentário @GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score 3):

Muito provavelmente. Mas é preciso fazer uma análise melhor, possível que em algum assunto só caiba um dos termos e o outro do ser um erro. Eu tenho certeza que a maioria eles são usadas como sinônimos, mas não podemos mesclá-las sem ter certeza que não trará problemas significativos e que não precisa de um tratamento adequado antes.

Eu acho que é a mesma, mas alguém precisa confirmar que não há exceções importantes.

Precisa ver se [array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) não pode ser a mesma também. E aí quem saber [vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vetor) e [vector](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vector).

O mesmo ocorre com [list](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) e [lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lista).

Parecem obviamente a mesma, mas não sei se todas perguntas forma usadas de forma que tanto faz usar uma ou outra.

Comment: OK, isso quer dizer, deveríamos olhar todas as perguntas da tag matriz e ver se algumas que estão como matriz devem ir para matrix também? Para o lado inverso analisei e não vejo motivo para manter as duas tags.

Comment: @DanielFalbel eu acho que sim, seria bom outras pessoas confirmarem isso.

Comment: Eu juro que não quero ser chato (de novo rs), mas esse parece ser um caso semelhante ao da tag 'table' que discutimos uma vez. Não? Considerando as conclusões daquela vez, talvez fosse bom tratar essa da mesma forma (pode ser relacionada com array ou vetor, como vc bem disse, mas eu imagino que pode ter relação também com matriz matemática, com matriz de rotação do OpenGL, ... etc). Em certas linguagens ainda há distinções (matrix vs array no Numpy em Python, por exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151128/what-are-the-differences-between-numpy-arrays-and-matrices-which-one-should-i-u)

Comment: @LuizVieira é o que eu penso, cada palavra pode ter um contexto diferente. Mas pode não ter também. Outro ponto a se observar é se é usado corretamente em uma pergunta e todo o resto incorretamente. Não que eu acho que o uso incorreto seja motivo para matar um *tag*, mas se o correto é praticamente desnecessário, pode ser uma boa.

Comment: Eu não sei dizer quanto as tags auxiliam nos mecanismos de busca... O meu uso de tags é especificamente para seguir perguntas que acredito ter conhecimento para responder. Para mim, a existência de múltiplas tags para dizer a mesma coisa é muito ruim pois, se por exemplo, eu pensar que posso responder perguntas relacionadas a 'matrizes' terei que seguir duas tags (o que para mim significa todo dia entrar na página delas e ver as novas perguntas) Isso vai se multiplicando quando tem `list` e `lista`, `tuple` e `tupla`, etc. Seria bom se no nosso site tivéssemos aquelas tabs (que nem no SO)...

Comment: @DanielFalbel agora imagina uma pergunta ter uma *tag*, mas ela não é sobre aquilo porque não tinha a *tag* adequada, complica, né? Seguir várias *tags* não me parece ser nenhum problema.

Comment: Nesse caso eu edito e coloco a tag correta. Para mim é trabalhoso, mas isso é só uma opinião pessoal. Acho o trabalho de seguir varias tags maior do que editar algumas perguntas que vierem com a tag errada. Para mim, é pior deixar de ver uma pergunta do que ver algumas a mais e editar. (Mas reforço: é completamente aceitavel que outras pessoas pensem exatamente o contrário)

Comment: @DanielFalbel como vai colocar a *tag* correta se é para acabar com ela?

Comment: Se realmente tiver necessidade cria-se a tag correta. Até agora, olhando as tags matrix a matriz não apareceu necessidade de ter as duas, me parece mais escolha aleatória do usuário.

Comment: @DanielFalbel mas você está propondo eliminá-la.

Comment: Por ora sim, se houver necessidade no futuro, recriamos.

Comment: @DanielFalbel mas se elas são a mesma não dá para recriar. Até dá, mas teria que desfazer o que foi feito, então tem que ter certeza antes de fazer. E pra falar a verdade eu eu tenho dúvidas se não haverá problemas. Cada vez mais me convenço que não tem solução boa para as *tags*. Resolve um problema e causa outro. veja que quase ninguém concorda que sua pergunta é relevante e que minha resposta ajuda em alguma coisa, portanto é difícil fazer algo com um mínimo de certeza que é o correto. Ainda vou pensar mais sobre o assunto de *tags* no geral.

Comment: Concordo, talvez não seja mesmo relevante... Eu acho que não precisamos prever se perguntas novas vão aparecer que precisem desambiguação das tags. Imagine que daqui um tempo criem uma linguagem de programação chamada matrix, logo teríamos que diferenciar perguntas sobre matriz de perguntas sobre matrix... Teremos que nos adaptar. Até agora essas duas tags estão sendo usadas aleatóriamente, para mim é melhor que sejam uma só. Se aparecer a necessidade de começar a separá-las, separamos...

Comment: @DanielFalbel é uma argumento.